# State communication between child and parent in React.js not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to communicate state between two different js files using React.

The parent class, break.js, is defined as such:

```
export default function AlertDialog(props) {
   const [demoOpen, setDemoOpen] = React.useState(true);
   
   // If statements that determine which component trigger is left out
   var trigger = <Demo4 term={props.term} onKeep={() => setDemoOpen(false)} />
   
   // After 60 seconds id demoOpen is false, close the dialog box
   useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(demoOpen);
      if (demoOpen !== true) {
        handleClose();
        setDid(true);
      }
    }, 60000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <Dialog
          disableBackdropClick
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
           {/* other dialog content left out */}
           <DialogContent>
              { trigger }
           </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    </div>
  );

}
```

The Demo4 file is defined as such:

```
export default function Demo4(props) {
 
 const enableButtonHandler = (event) => {
   // Stuff here
 }
 const thisIsNoButton = (bool) => {
   // Interaction times written to firebase
 }
 
 return(
      <div>
         <Dialog
            disableBackdropClick
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            onEnter={time_func}>
            {/* Other Dialog content left out*/}
            <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  style={{ fontSize: 10, paddingRight: 10}}
                  onClick={() => {
                    // Call break.js setDemoOpen()
                    props.onKeep();
                    thisIsNoButton(false);
                  }}
                  color="error"
                  disabled={disabled}
                  onChange={enableButtonHandler}
                >
                  No
             </Button>
         </Dialog>
      </div>

   );
}
```

My big problem is that the state never changes when written to the console in the useEffect function in break.js! It always persists as true.

I've thought that maybe I misunderstood the usage of onClick with mui's button component so I played around with just calling props.onKeep but that still does not work. thisIsNoButton function works correctly.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, it's just that your `useEffect` will get called only once when your parent component gets mounted.
That is because you have passed an empty array `[]` as a dependency to `useEffect`.

As per your question, it seems you want to execute code inside `useEffect` whenever `demoOpen` gets updated. If that's true then you need to pass `demoOpen` in dependency array to `useEffect` as shown below:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(demoOpen);
      if (demoOpen !== true) {
        handleClose();
        setDid(true);
      }
    }, 60000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [demoOpen]);  // <= pass demoOpen to dependency array
```

This will make your `useEffect` run when your component gets mounted for the first time and after that whenever `demoOpen` changes and you should see the updated values correctly.

More on `useEffect` [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#reference)

Comment: I would like the useEffect to only run once. I should've described it's use better. A dialog pops up at 30 seconds from load that notifies users that they can't interact with the platform for 30 seconds (60 seconds in total). In the 30 seconds that the break is active, another dialog popsup as a security warning, but it closes once the break ends. I want it to stay open past this break ONLY IF the user doesn't interact the no button, else the rest of the break occurs. The problem is the state is not changing when I hit the no button, not the useEffect.